# How do I add PHPadmin to my bootstrap.sh commands?

Tags: vagrant-provision

I've been away from PHP nearly four years, I've been working in javascript and Node.JS instead. I have a memory of what tools I was comfortable working with.. it's a rusty memory how it all went together. I've followed [Traversy's tutorial to get the LAMP box running](https://youtu.be/vBreXjkizgo)
and have [connected from MySQL WorkBench.](http://www.bentedder.com/using-mysql-workbench-with-vagrant/)

**I'd like to use PHPAdmin**, *How do I add PHPadmin to my bootstrap.sh commands?*

[Installing phpMyAdmin On Vagrant](https://danielpataki.com/phpmyadmin-on-vagrant/)
I like this version best, cause each domain has it's own **/phpadmin**, but I don't understand how he is editing the config file from inside **bootstrap.sh**

[A super-simple Vagrant LAMP stack bootstrap (installable with one command)](https://www.dev-metal.com/super-simple-vagrant-lamp-stack-bootstrap-installable-one-command/)
I tried this one first, but got an error from the first curly brace, saying it didn't recognize the character..

**bootstrap.sh**

```
# Use single quotes instead of double quotes to make it work with special-character passwords
PASSWORD='12345678'
PROJECTFOLDER='myproject'

# Update Packages
apt-get update
# Upgrade Packages
apt-get upgrade

# Basic Linux Stuff
apt-get install -y git

# Apache
apt-get install -y apache2

# Enable Apache Mods
a2enmod rewrite

#Add Onrej PPA Repo
apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update

# Install PHP
apt-get install -y php7.2

# PHP Apache Mod
apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.2

# Restart Apache
service apache2 restart

# PHP Mods
apt-get install -y php7.2-common
apt-get install -y php7.2-mcrypt
apt-get install -y php7.2-zip

# Set MySQL Pass
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $PASSWORD'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $PASSWORD'

# Install MySQL
apt-get install -y mysql-server

# PHP-MYSQL lib
apt-get install -y php7.2-mysql

# Install phpmyadmin
# apt-get install phpmyadmin

# Restart Apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# Box Settings
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

# Provider Settings  
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = 2048
  vb.cpus = 4
  end

# Network Settings  
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

# Folder Settings  
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"] }

# Provision Settings  
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```